# I cannot make executable from LLVMGetFunctionAddress

Tags: c, llvm

I am trying to a executable based of my `LLVMModule` and here is my init

```c
    LLVMInitializeCore(LLVMGetGlobalPassRegistry());  
    LLVMInitializeAllTargets();
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs();
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();
    LLVMInitializeAllAsmParsers();
    LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();

    context = LLVMGetGlobalContext(); 
    module = LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("main",context);   
    LLVMSetTarget(module, "arm64-apple-macosx13.0.0");
    LLVMSetDataLayout(module, "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128");
```

and I simply trying to run this in the end of the my program

```c
    char* error = NULL;
    if (LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule(&engine, module, &error) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", error);
        LLVMDisposeMessage(error);
        return;
    }
    LLVMGetFunctionAddress(engine, "main");
```

and I just get Segmentation Fault.
I tried just to include a simple main function and a empty "entry"